# Lists, Datasets, or Datatables?

Tags: c#, asp.net

So I am new to programming all together and trying to figure out what type of object I should be using.  I have a SQL database that I am pulling multiple fields from multiple tables into a datagrid view.  These fields all equal to a barcode and I also have 20 asp textbox server controls that the scanned bar codes will be entered into.  I need to be able to work with the data in the grid view by looking at the 20 textboxes and comparing it to the data in the gridview (Basically verifying the barcodes are correct) and then update the database with a separate button.

So here is my question.  Being new to programming I have placed my results into a DataTable and placed it into a session variable.  Everything is working fine, but I don't want to learn to program inefficiently.  This is my first program so I am asking whether I should be doing it this way or should I create a class with properties and then a list or is there another way I just don't know about yet.

I am currently reading a few different books and have access to all of the pluralsight.com videos for the training.

Again I am not really looking for code specifics as of yet, more of a from an efficiency standpoint how should I tackle this?

Comment: "efficiency" is ambiguous: if you mean raw performance (CPU, memory, etc) then: list of POCO. If you mean lines of code: datatable; or compromise in the middle and use an ORM

Comment: @OP - why are you storing it in Session?

Answer (score 0):

The fastest using .net is use a datareader and use poco class to have everything in objects.

If you want a little help creating the class for the data you can use an ORM mapper like entity framework or hibernate.

If you like to code your class and use linq for your queries you can go with entity framework code first.